# calculating dates in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

i have two(2) tables

#### employee

employee name, contract start date,  contract end date , total vacation days

#### employee_info

employee_name,leave start date and leave end date (date pickers), leave amount(number field).

This will show in a calendar when the employee takes his leave (personal,vacation)

i have 3 scenarios i would like help with.

(1) how can i show holidays on the calendar

(2) how can i exclude holidays and weekends when i use my date picker field to calculate days (**i have a pl/sql that automatically calculate the leave amount**) and

(3) how can i show a notification that you need to take all your vacation one month before your contract expires.

```
declare
  leave_end_date DATE;
  leave_start_date DATE;
Begin
  leave_start_date := to_date(:P6_leave_START_DATE );
  leave_end_date := to_date(:P6_leave_END_DATE );
  RETURN (leave_end_date-leave_start_date)-1;

End;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your style and code properly. Currently your question is not readable.

Comment: hope this helps

Comment: Please show us your code and what you already tried.

Comment: declare
  leave_end_date DATE;
  leave_start_date DATE;
Begin
  leave_start_date := to_date(:P6_leave_START_DATE );
  leave_end_date := to_date(:P6_leave_END_DATE );
  RETURN (leave_end_date-leave_start_date)-1;

End;